# multiple modal and change url in ui-router Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want use multiple modal in one $state and i want change url.

I use ui-router for route

For example in user list after clicking on edit, url change to /users/123/edit and the modal show. clicking on details, url change to /users/123/details and the modal show.

How can i do it?

Comment: What you have done till now? Show some sample code.

Comment: i have no idea for solve this problem, i search on google and people suggest use onEnter in ui-router, but onEnter doesn't my answer because i want multiple modal, do you have idea?